# Netbeans: Hide specific lines in source code

Tags: netbeans

Is it possible in Netbeans to hide some pieces of code, especially debugging code, from the Source Code View?

For example I would want to hide: `System.out.println("DEBUG: ...");`, with `...` being whatever is needed to print some variables.

I don't like that it misses up how my code looks, but if I remove it entirely then I might need it again tomorrow for example.

Answer (score 6):

In NetBeans you can hide code in editor folds. Just put the code you would like to hide in between comments of the form:

```
//<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="comment">
//</editor-fold>
```

For example, I use this to automatically hide code with sensitive information when screen casting, giving presentations, or the like. This way the code is still functional, but I can only expose the parts that are important to the discussion.

```
//<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="API-KEY">
private static final String API_KEY = "Not to be shared";
//</editor-fold>
```

You can also add a fold by selecting the code you wish to hide with the mouse. A light bulb icon will appear in the editor's margin. Click the light bulb and pick

`Surround with //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="comment">...`

to have the editor add the needed comments for you.

Comment: Thanks Sir, actually looking for it

Answer (score 2):

Netbeans editor allows you to hide (fold):

- entire methods
- inner classes
- imports
- Javadoc and
- initial Comment and tags.

Discreet statement lines are not part of this list.

Options-->Editor-->General allows you the control of what will be collapsed.

[image]

[image]

Imagine the mess you would get into, if you have a few selected hidden statement lines and you try to find what goes wrong in a source code you can partially view.

Print statements is not the way you should use in order to test your code. Do it with the excellent [Visual Debugger](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/debug-visual.html) or with [JUnit](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/junit-intro.html). This way you will have no more issues with mixing debugging print instructions with your actual code.